# Getting "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" with Celery

Tags: python, celery

I am beginner.I'm running a task in Celery and getting this strange error

> maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

You can check the full error in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Wu1vgsW0)

I don't quite understand because I haven't change anything and yesterday it was working fine. I ran the task without celery in the python interpreter and it runs fine. You can check the function [here.](http://pastebin.com/0rXn36Zw) Finally, for what it is worth, this task is getting created 12 times by an other task.

Do you see anything that could create such an error?

EDIT:

This is the task I call this function / task

```
@celery.task(ignore_result=True)
def get_classicdata(leagueid):
    print "getting team data for %s"%leagueid
    returned_data = {}
    for team in r.smembers('league:%s'%leagueid):
        data = scrapteam.delay(team,r.get('currentgw'))
        returned_data[team] = data.get()
```

Comment: How and where do you call this function?

Comment: @alexvassel I have edited my question with the task where I call the function/task

Comment: i can not understand your code. What is r? And what returns r.smembers() and r.get() and what the heck is r)?

Comment: It's how I access to the redis DB.

r.smembers('league:%s'%leagueid) return a set of IDs
r.get('currentgw') return a int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks fine. The traceback implies that the returned object somewhere cannot be pickled, but your returned 'team' data structure is a dictionary containing a non-recursive data structure of basic types, so that can't cause a problem. For better remote debugging, please put a print statement before the "return team", so that it shows the content of the team. You might also try just having it return a {} and see if that changes thing.

Then also add a debugging print statement in get_classicdata showing the content of data.get(), as well as something just before the return there, in order to verify if that function reaches completion.

Comment: For whatever reason, I added the print statements you recommended and it started to work again.

I'm going to leave them there for a while, if the error comesback.

Thx for the help!

Comment: One long-shot possibility: perhaps your network file system has screwy timestamps so the celery tasks were picking up an old .pyc file with buggy code, rather than the correct .py file.